# How to read the value stored in a Key from the Registry using C

Tags: c, registry, registrykey

Hi I'm trying to read the value stored in a registry key using C code. I've tried the following code. It's not generating any compilation errors. But I get only the first letter of the string as the output. Here is my code sample

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>



#define TOTALBYTES    8192
#define BYTEINCREMENT 4096
#define BUFFER 8192



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char value[255];
DWORD BufferSize = BUFFER;
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Test\\subkey"), TEXT("blockedurlslist"), RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
printf("%s",value);
system("pause");
}
```

Please help me if anyone has got an idea

Comment: Looks a little evil... One point: you don't want to be passing a buffer that is only 255 bytes long and telling the OS that it is 8kb.

Comment: Maybe you want to be passing `(PVOID)value`?

Answer (score 1):

For a start you are not checking whether or not the call to `RegGetValue` succeeded. Always check the return values of Win32 API calls.

But what is happening is pretty clear. Whenever a function returns a string with only the first character, the most likely cause is that the function is returning UTF-16 data which you interpret as ANSI. Your string will contain an English character which is encoded in UTF-16 with a 0 as the second byte. And when interpreted as ANSI that 0 is treated as the string terminator.

You need to declare your buffer as containing a wide character payload. Since you are using `TCHAR` then you would do it like this:

```
TCHAR value[255];
```

And the buffer size is

```
DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(value);
```

You will need to change your `printf` to be able to print out a wide string.

If I were you I would not be using `TCHAR`. I would recommend that you decide to use Unicode throughout your code. It makes it much simpler for you to understand and I doubt that you need to support Windows 98 these days.

Answer (score 0):

What is the call returning? If it's not returning `ERROR_SUCCESS`, it failed. You can inspect the value of `BufferSize` after the call to find out how much data the API claims to have returned.

As pointed out in a comment, you should say:

```
char value[BUFFER];
DWORD BufferSize = sizeof value;
```

Since now you're lying to the API about your buffer size, which invites buffer overwrites.

Perhaps it's returning data in 16-bit characters, and you're printing with an 8-bit call, thus interpreting the interspersed 0-bytes as string terminators.